# How to speed up python views in CouchDB?

Tags: python, performance, couchdb

I'm working on my CouchDB with Python, cause I love python. The problem is: On my machine (it's a Seagate Dockstar) it's quite slow. How can I increase the speed?

a) I've tried to use psyco. It's not available for that plattform.
b) I've tried to put the imports outside my function-definitons. This doesn't work since the couchpy throws an error because in the file there's not a parsable function.

What else should be possible? I don't want to learn erlang...

Comment: Can you show what you did and what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Have you tried [profiling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+profiling) your app to see where it's spending its time?

Comment: hmmm...it's more or less closed-source. I think the main cpu power is spent with beautifulsoup and urlparse. maybe I'm faster with a simple regexp. I will try to make some profiling...

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you didn't want to learn Erlang, but I really think you should [Learn You Some Erlang for Great Good!](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/)